# How to prevent Windows 10 from downloading and installing updates before the Boot Camp Support Software is installed?

Tags: bootcamp, windows

Microsoft is allowing users to download and install (but not activate) Windows 10 Pro 64 bit without using a Product key.

I tried doing a clean install of Windows 10 on my mid 2007, 20 inch iMac. During installation, I was not asked if I wanted to disable Windows Update. Windows ended up downloading drivers before I could install the Boot Camp software. Some of the drivers installed but most failed.

Is there a way to install the Boot Camp software before updates are downloaded?
Or, can updating be disabled during the Windows 10 installation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below are some basic steps to install the Boot Camp Support Software and configure Windows Update before updates are downloaded from Microsoft.

> *Windows Update can only be configured if you are installing Windows 10 Pro or better. I do not know of a way to configure Windows Update for Windows 10 Home. The steps given below can still be used to install the Boot Camp Support Software.*

Hint: For a better view, click on an image or open an image in a new window.

1. Before installing Windows 10, make sure your computer can not
   communicate with the internet. If the computer is hardwired to the
   internet, disconnect it now.
2. Start installing Windows 10.
3. You may be asked to connect to the internet via Wi-Fi. If a window
   similar to below appears, click on "Skip this step".

   [image]
4. When you reach the following screen, put the computer in Audit mode
   by pressing the following keys. With the
   <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd> keys held down, press the
   <kbd>F3</kbd> key. Hold all three keys down for about 3 seconds or
   until the computer starts to reboot.

   [image]
5. If you see the screen below, do nothing. The computer will login
   automatically to the Administrator account.

   [image: 413]
6. Eventually, you should get the following screen showing the
   Administrator's desktop. You can close the "System Preparation Tool
   3.14" window.

   [image]
7. Check the clock and make any needed corrections. Right click on the
   clock shown on the task bar at the bottom right of the screen and
   select "Adjust date/time". See image shown below.

   [image]
8. Install the Boot Camp Support Software (BCSS) by opening the setup
   Application in the appropriate BCSS folder. If you get a Windows
   version error message similar to what is shown below, proceed to
   step 9.

   [image: 401]

   If you get a Boot Camp x64 error message similar to what is shown
   below, proceed to step 10. Otherwise, goto step 11.

   [image: 800]
9. You can remedy the situation by right clicking on the highlighted
   setup application entry and selecting "Properties", as shown below.

   [image: 402]

   Next, click on the "Compatibility" tab, check off "Run this program
   in compatibility for:" box and select the appropriate previous
   version of Windows. An illustration is shown below.

   [image: 404]

   Click the "OK" button and a open the setup application to install
   the BCSS. If the computer reboots, you can close the "System
   Preparation Tool 3.14" window and any Boot Camp windows. Proceed to
   step 11.
10. You can remedy the situation by using the Finder application to
     navigate to the Windows Installer Package named "BootCamp64" or
     similar file. Right click on the file entry and select
     "Properties", as shown below.

    [image: 801]

    Next, click on the "Compatibility" tab, check off "Run this program
     in compatibility for:" box. An illustration is shown below.

    [image: 802]

    Click the "OK" button. Right click on the file entry and select
     "Install", as shown below. This starts the installation of the
     BCSS. If the computer reboots, you can close the "System
     Preparation Tool 3.14" window and any Boot Camp windows.

    [image: 803]
11. If you do not want to configure Windows Update or have Windows 10
    Home, you should skip this step. To proceed, right click on the
    Start button on the taskbar and select "Run", as shown below.

    [image: 405]

    In the popup windows, enter "gpedit.msc" and click the Ok button, as
    shown below.

    [image: 406]

    Select "Local Computer Policy→Computer Configuration→Administrative
    Templates→Windows Components→Windows Update", as shown below.

    [image: 407]

    Next, right click on "Configure Automatic Updates" and select
    "Edit". The "Configure Automatic Updates" windows should appear as
    shown below.

    [image: 408]

    If you want to "Never check for updates" click the "Disabled"
    button, otherwise click the "Enabled" button and choose your option.
    The result from choosing option 2 is shown below.

    [image: 409]

    When finished, click the "OK" button to close the window. Also,
    close the "Local Group Policy Editor" window. Next, Click on the
    Start button on the task bar and select "Settings→Update &
    security→Windows Update→Check for updates". When the following
    message occurs, click "Advanced options".

    [image: 410]

    Inspect the window to confirm you selection. Below is the correct
    window for option 2.

    [image: 411]

    Close the "Settings" window.
12. Connect your computer to the internet. If you computer was hardwired
    to the internet, plug it back in now. If you were using Wi-Fi,
    enable it and join a network.
13. If the "System Preparation Tool 3.14" window is not displayed,
    reboot the computer.
14. Click the "OK" button in the "System Preparation Tool 3.14" window.
     Use the default settings shown in the image below.

    [image: 412]

When the computer reboots, you will have left the Audit mode. You should boot to the following display.

[image]

On my computer, I was able to select the "United States (Apple)" keyboard. You may want to check if a better choice exists than the default keyboard.

At this point, you can continue with the Windows 10 installation.

### Additional Notes:

There is a downloadable ["Show or hide updates" troubleshooter package](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3073930) from Microsoft, that will allow you to review and/or hide updates before downloading and/or installing. This option is described in an [answer](https://superuser.com/questions/946957/stopping-automatic-updates-windows-10/948069#948069) to "Stopping automatic updates windows 10".

Personally, I found this software to be unpredictable. I could get the software to hide an update, but I had trouble getting a hidden update to install.

Comment: This is an amazingly in-depth solution. Keep up the good work on Apple.SE!

Answer (score 1):

Where to start…? …

This is the current picture as I understand it, & may be subject to change/correction

To get your 'free' Win 10 you must upgrade an existing activated installation, otherwise you will have to enrol in the Insider Program when it reopens to continue to use it [or keep installing fresh every month to a VM that cannot be identified as being the 'same machine']

If you install clean from the Media Creator tool on an external USB key etc, you may not be able to get past the 'enter a Win 10 key' screen. People have had varying results at that point, some get the 'skip' button, some do not. [I have yet to figure out what causes this difference]

Upgrading an existing Win 7 or 8 OS would also at least keep the existing Boot Camp drivers in place - possibly better than trying to inject outdated drivers after the fact.

There are no Boot Camp drivers yet for Win 10.

Also, unless you are using Win 10 Enterprise [which has no free upgrade path], you cannot switch off automatic updates, only defer them til next reboot.

Comment: I just assume that when Apple releases Boot Camp drivers for Win 10, they will not work for my iMac. I have always used "Boot Camp Support Software 4.0.4033" for my 64 bit clean Windows 7 and 8 installs. I did get a 'skip' button twice during the Windows 10 install. Windows 8.1 was installed in a different partition when I installed Windows 10. I don't know if this makes a difference.

Comment: I guess it is possible to configure Automatic Updates. At a Command Prompt enter `gpedit.msc`, then navigate to "Local Computer Policy->Computer Configuration->Administrative Templates->Windows Components->Windows Updates->Configure Automatic Updates". Any changes are not reflected under "Start menu->Settings->Update & security->Windows Update->Advanced Options" until you manual check for updates. Note: Option 1 has been replaced by the Disabled button.

Comment: I'm not sure how you would do that before the fact, though. As it stands, if you upgrade an existing installation, you get the option to look for updates at install or not. That still may be your safest bet.

Comment: When I asked my question, I was not trying to debate whether a clean install is better than an upgrade. Yet, your answer does lead to new questions. Can you do a clean install and activate, if you get Windows 10 from the insider program?

Comment: You can't activate Insider Previews right now - they blocked all the keys about 2 weeks ago - though you can install them & have them nag your life out with the 'Windows needs activating' overlay, even over movies & fullscreen apps :( No news on when the next round of insiders will be started. BTW - that's why my answer began 'Where to start...' because there's a lot of new info for people to absorb in a short time ;)

Comment: I did not mention "Preview". I meant the version of Windows 10 currently offered by the inside program. Here is what I have done so far. I download Windows 10 using the `MediaCreationTool64` and installed in a empty partition. I could not activate. Next, I posted my question. Based on your answer, I download Windows 10 from the Window Insider Program and upgraded my Windows 8.1 partition. This installation activated BOTH partitions. My new question just asked if a clean install with Windows 10 from the Inside program would have activated. You answer seemed to indicate it would.

Comment: I've never tried an Insider Preview as an update, only clean install, so idk the answer to that - other than it seems to have worked for you;) If you do it as a clean install right now, it will not activate, because the keys were all revoked.... unless they changed that policy again in the past few days

Answer (score -2):

TO prevent windows from updating automatically, you have to make sure that windows update service is disabled. It is very easy to do rather than going through the hassle explained above. Here is the link of the youtube video which explains how to disable windows update services. Check it out : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Efm9tQwtBM0

Comment: Your answer would be improved if you edited your answer to describe how to do it - that way, if the video is deleted from Youtube your answer will still be useful (and some workplaces block Youtube).